# Are there names for components of a decimal expansion?

Tags: terminology, decimal-expansion

Consider the following equations:

$$\frac{6758}{87} = 77.67816091954022988505747126436781609195402298850574712643...$$

Repeating decimal: $6781609195402298850574712643$.

$$\frac{6758}{875} = 7.723428571428571...$$

Repeating decimal: $428571$.

Both of these equations result in infinite decimal expansions with repeating sequences, but there is a difference. In the first equation, the repeating decimal sequence begins immediately after the decimal point, and in the second equation, the repeating decimal sequence begins $3$ decimal places after the decimal point, where the $3$ digits immediately after the decimal point are $723$.

First question - why in some decimal expansions does the repeating sequence begin a few digits after the decimal point?

Second question - are there names for these components; i.e. $$[\mathrm{integer}].[\mathrm{leading\space fraction}][\mathrm{repeating\space fraction}]$$

Comment: You can use name prefixes used in physic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix

Comment: There is a non-repeating sequence prior to the [repetend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal) when the denominator is a multiple of $2$ or $5$